# Catch exception appropriate when disposing of the result?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Consider the following piece of code:

```
public static Stream OpenWavStream(string path)
{
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

    try
    {
        stream.Seek(44, SeekOrigin.Current);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        stream.Dispose();
        throw;
    }

    return stream;
}
```

I'm opening a wav stream whose data always starts at offset 44. If seeking to that offset fails, the stream is disposed, otherwise it is returned. Considering that [catch (Exception) is considered bad practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137.aspx), is it appropriate in this case?

Should one rather research the concrete exceptions (even though the stream should be disposed if any kind of exception happens within the Stream.Seek call) or move it into a finally block?

Comment: read the msdn documentation again on this .. it explains on how you shouldn't catch general exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catch (Exception)` is bad practice if you are using it to swallow exceptions and not handling them. You are immediately re-throwing the exception, and doing it properly (you're not doing `throw ex;` for example). You will need to dispose the stream for *any* exception, so you should not catch specific exceptions here.

Your code is perfectly fine. However, I am skeptical about the usefulness of the method. Without seeing the rest of the application, it might make sense for the callee to create the stream within a `using` block, even with a helper method.

```
//In your callee code
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
{
    ConfigureStream(steam);
    //Other stuff..
}

public static void ConfigureStream(Stream stream)
{
    stream.Seek(44, SeekOrigin.Current);
}
```

Or, you could check the length of the stream first, to avoid the exception entirely.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I'd prefer using if I could, but I can't because at the time of opening the file the wav file is not complete yet, so sadly that's not an option. The exceptions I'm worrying about are IOException, SecurityException, UnauthorizedAccessException. Seeking beyond the end of the stream is supported, so there won't be any issue with that I presume.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.. you should still be able to use `using`. All it does is wrap your code in a `try {} finally {}` block to handle the dispose for you. In any case, you always need to dispose the stream on an exception, so `catch (Exception)` is required

Answer (score 2):

Only if the Stream fails to load. Something I use:

```
string fileName = "C:\\PCM.wav";

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
{
LogStatus("Wave file not found.");
return;
}
else
{
WaveFileByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
LogStatus("Wave file Loaded!" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

This works fine.

then to play/Use:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer soundPlayer;
soundPlayer.Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
soundPlayer.Stream.Write(WaveFileByteArray, 0, WaveFileByteArray.Length);
soundPlayer.Play();
```

Relying on an Exception to catch possible errors, like is presented, is not best practice, unless the error is unexpected. Dealing with possible Errors before they occur is best practice.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I can't read the file into memory simply because at the time of opening the file stream the wav file is not complete yet. Furthermore I can't delay it either because wav data is needed just when those bits are written out. Thanks for the SoundPlayer code, but I don't need it :)

Comment: You cant call: "stream.Seek(44, SeekOrigin.Current);" if there is no 44 to call. You need to rethink your strategy. Maybe multiple Wav Files? Not enough information is provided.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a using block in calling method and leave the closing of steam to the system. using will close the stream even if there is an exception.

```
public static Stream OpenWavStream(string path)
    {
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        stream.Seek(44, SeekOrigin.Current);
        return stream;
    }

public static void UseWaveStream()
    {
        try
        {
            using(Stream thisStream = OpenWavStream("C:\\myfile.txt"))
            {
                 // do whatever 
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't use the using statement, because data is written to the wav stream after it is opened. I can't read the file into memory simply because at the time of opening the file stream the wav file is not complete yet. Furthermore I can't delay it either because wav data is needed just when those bits are written out.